# Clear all inputs inside row

Tags: jquery

`var new_row` has type `Object[tr]`.
How can I clear all inputs inside this row?

Comment: A little more information would be useful...Some sample HTML and the JavaScript you have tried.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(new_row).find("input").val("");
```

Comment: There ... that would seemingly clear the values.  I don't know why I translated clear to remove in my brain.  Thanks for the catch.